# if "a.pyc" file exist then delete "a.py" file

Tags: python, file, ubuntu, centos

I want to delete all the *.py file in a directory if *.pyc file is exists.
for example: 
[image]

I use ubuntu 12.04 and centos 7 OS.

Comment: May I ask for the reason of doing that?

Comment: @Carsten I tried to compile all the *.py file to *.pyc and delete all the *.py file.
But in runtime, some excution will call *.py file, so i can't delete all the *.py file.

Comment: @KlausD. My reason is as the answer for Carsten

Comment: @Eveenn that's not a reason, you left out the "why" :)

Comment: @Kos uh.. I need to remove *.py file to reduce the project size and try to avoid the source code be modified.
Is this anwser to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Python's `os.walk` function, and create sets of matching file extensions as follows:

```
import os

root = r'/root/folder'

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
    py_files = set()
    pyc_files = set()

    for file in filenames:
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if ext == '.py':
            py_files.add(name)
        if ext == '.pyc':
            pyc_files.add(name)

    for file in py_files.intersection(pyc_files):
        delete_file = os.path.join(dirpath, file + '.py')
        print 'Removing - {}'.format(delete_file)
        os.remove(delete_file)
```

Where the two sets intersect, the file can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Using os walk to iterate through directories and adding paths then figuring out if it has py and pyc files then remove py files accordingly.

May have some bugs but you can figure out from here

```
from os import walk,remove
mypath = "yourpath"
f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(mypath):
    f.extend(map(lambda filename:(dirpath)+filename,filenames))

f=sorted(f)
for i in f:
    if i.endswith(".py"):
        if i+"c" in f:
            remove(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me.